# Why can't I extract text between patterns with varying text length

Tags: regex, r

I have a column in a data frame with characters that need to be split into columns. My code seems to break when the string in the column has a length of 12 but it works fine when the string has a length of 11.

```
S99.ABCD{T}
S99.ABCD{V}
S99.ABCD{W}
S99.ABCD{Y}
Q100.ABCD{A}
Q100.ABCD{C}
Q100.ABCD{D}
Q100.ABCD{E}
```

An example of the ideal format is on the left, what I'm getting is on the right:

```
ID    WILD RES MUT | ID    WILD RES MUT
ABCD  S    99  T   | ABCD  S    99  T
...                | ...
ABCD  Q    100 A   | .ABC  Q    100 { 
...                | ...
```

My current solution is the following:

```
    data <- data.frame(ID = substr(mdata$substitution,
                                   gregexpr(pattern = "\\.",
                                   mdata$substitution)[[1]] + 1,
                                   gregexpr(pattern = "\\{",
                                   mdata$substitution)[[1]] - 1),
                       WILD = substr(mdata$substitution, 0, 1),
                       RES = gsub("[^0-9]","", mdata$substitution),
                       MUT = substr(mdata$substitution,
                                    gregexpr(pattern = "\\{",
                                    mdata$substitution)[[1]] + 1,                                    
                                    gregexpr(pattern = "\\}",
                                    mdata$substitution)[[1]] - 1))
```

I'm not sure why my code isn't working, I thought using gregexpr I would be able to find where the pattern was in the string to find out the position of characters I want to extract but it doesn't work when the length of the string changes.

Comment: `read.table(text = gsub('(\\D+)(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\{(\\w)\\}', '\\3 \\1 \\2 \\4', dd$V1))`

Answer (score 0):

Using this example you can do what you want

```
test=c("S99.ABCD{T}",
       "S99.ABCD{V}",
       "S99.ABCD{W}",
       "S99.ABCD{Y}",
       "Q100.ABCD{A}",
       "Q100.ABCD{C}",
       "Q100.ABCD{D}",
       "Q100.ABCD{E}")
library(stringr)
test=str_remove(test,pattern = "\\}")
testdf=as.data.frame(str_split(test,pattern = "\\.|\\{",simplify = T))
testdf$V4substring(testdf$V1, 1, 1)                   
testdf$V5=substring(testdf$V1, 2)
```